# Can't write values of a form to file

Tags: php, forms, preg-replace

I have a form. Something like this:

[image]

Code:

```
    <form action="rewrite.php" method="get">
<?php 
    foreach ($tomb2[1] as $key => $metaname){
        $talalat = $tomb[1][$key]; 
        echo '<p>' . "$metaname\n" . '</p>' . '<br>' . '<input type="text" name="metavalue[]" value="' . "$talalat\n" . '">' . '<br>';
    }
?>    
<input type="submit" name="Generálás" value="insert" onclick="insert()" />
</form>
```

The values of the form are needed to be written to an xml file:

```
<property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="2" name="ALALALAL">4
</property>
<property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="3" name="MACABSZ">4
</property>
<property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="4" name="3">4
</property
><property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="5" name="4">4</property></Properties>
```

To the replace I use the following php code:

```
<?php 
$ertekek = $_GET["metavalue"];
 foreach ($ertekek as $alma ){
$rewrite= file_get_contents('docs/sablonTeszt20150805/docProps/custom.xml');
$rewrite = preg_replace('_<vt:lpwstr>(.*?)</vt:lpwstr>_', "$alma\n" , $rewrite);
file_put_contents('docs/sablonTeszt20150805/docProps/custom.xml', $rewrite );
 }
 ?>
```

The code is working, however only the last value of the form is written to the xml file. I need the following xml:

```
 <property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="2" name="ALALALAL">1
    </property>
    <property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="3" name="MACABSZ">2
    </property>
    <property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="4" name="3">3
    </property
    ><property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="5" name="4">4</property></Properties>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Glups. Before doing any replacement, you should test if `$_GET["metavalue"]` exists and check what it contains. To edit an xml file, use DOMDocument or xslt, not a regex.

Comment: $_GET["metavalue"] is working, it contains the values of the form (attached image). Later I plan to use DOMDocument, now I want to make it functional.

Comment: What does your original XML file look like, before the replacements? You posted the same XML code twice.

Comment: Are you sure it is only the *last* value that is written, or is it the *first*?

Comment: I am sure it is the last value. (In the first xml all the values are 4, I also tested it with other values). The orginal xml is the following (almost the same, with different values):

Comment: <property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="2" name="ALALALAL"><vt:lpwstr>asdasda</vt:lpwstr></property>
<property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="3" name="MACABSZ"><vt:lpwstr>ooooo</vt:lpwstr>
</property><property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="4" name="3"><vt:lpwstr>c</vt:lpwstr></property>
<property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="5" name="4"><vt:lpwstr>d</vt:lpwstr></property></Properties>

Comment: Coun't the number of values (n) you have to replace (if you don't already know it). Then use DOMDocument to replace the n nodeValues of the first n tags with a `for` loop. Your approach with `preg_replace` will not work because this function replace all occurrences in the string, that's why you always obtain the last value for each tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `preg_replace` function by default replaces *all* matches of the regular expression. Therefore after the first iteration, there are no more `<vt:lpwstr>` tags in your `XML`, and so any following iteration will not have any matches, and will not change the `XML` any more.

The basic fix is using the optional `limit` argument of `preg_replace`, and indicate you only want one replacement:

```
$rewrite = preg_replace('_<vt:lpwstr>(.*?)</vt:lpwstr>_',
                        "$alma\n", $rewrite, 1);
```

Now there are several small improvements you could make:

First, it is a waste of disk I/O to read and write the file in each iteration. Just do it once, outside the loop.

Secondly, you'll want to remove any white-space that would remain before and after the replaced value.

Putting that all together, you would get this:

```
$ertekek = $_GET["metavalue"];
$rewrite = file_get_contents('docs/sablonTeszt20150805/docProps/custom.xml');
foreach ($ertekek as $alma) {
    $rewrite = preg_replace('_\s*<vt:lpwstr>(.*?)</vt:lpwstr>\s*_', 
                            "$alma", $rewrite, 1);
}
file_put_contents('docs/sablonTeszt20150805/docProps/custom.xml', $rewrite);
```

There is a potential weakness still, in that this code relies on a certain order of the `metavalues` iterated. I am not sure this is guaranteed across all steps performed.

On a final note, regular expressions are not the ideal way to manipulate `XML` files. The [DOMDocument class in php](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) provides all you need to do that in a controlled way.

Comment: Even if you use the limit parameter, the problem stays the same since you will only replace the first tag (with the last value at the end).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, note that the first replacement will replace the first `<vt:lpwstr>` tag it finds, but will not re-insert that tag, so the number of occurrences of that tag has then decreased. The next iteration will find another `<vt:lpwstr>` tag, which then is the first, etc.

Comment: Indeed, you are right, I missed the fact that one `vt:lpwstr` tag is removed at each iteration. (but it stays an ugly way).

Comment: Yes, I agree it is not the advised way to do this, but Asker insisted in the comments that he wanted to make this work first, and then look at the better way (DOMDocument).

Comment: Asker is a noob (and he claims it). Do you think it is more simple or faster or a good idea to test with regex to be sure it works? It's only a waste of time.

Comment: By seeing the corrections as regards his repeated file open/close actions, and the use of the `limit` parameter, I honestly think he has learned something from it anyway. And he still is advised to look at `DOMDocument` now. So I don't think it was a waste of time. (Why did you add a random space in my post?)

Comment: It's a trick to remove a vote when it is frozen after a certain time ( you edit a post and you can remove a down/upvote).

Comment: Learned something. Thanks!